# CRM 2011 - Application Ribbon Throws An error while Importing

Tags: xml, ribbon, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to add a custom button to the "Main"-ribbon of a custom entity! I followed the example explained on http://mscrmshop.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-start-dialog-from-application_08.html... But i'm still getting the following error : **The ribbon item 'Sample.ave_student.MainTab.MyURL.CustomAction' is dependent on ribbon control id='Mscrm.HomepageGrid.ave_student.MainTab.Workflow.Controls'.**

My XML :

```
<ImportExportXml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Entities></Entities>
  <Roles></Roles>
  <Workflows></Workflows>
  <FieldSecurityProfiles></FieldSecurityProfiles>
  <Templates />
  <RibbonDiffXml>
    <CustomActions>
        <CustomAction Id="Sample.ave_student.MainTab.MyURL.CustomAction" Location="Mscrm.HomepageGrid.ave_student.MainTab.Workflow.Controls._children" Sequence="41">
            <CommandUIDefinition>
                <Button Id="Sample.ave_student.MainTab.MyURL.Button" Command="javascript.Command" LabelText="eID" ToolTipTitle="eID" ToolTipDescription="eID" TemplateAlias="o1" Image16by16="$webresource:ave_eid16x16" Image32by32="$webresource:ave_eid32x32" />
            </CommandUIDefinition>
        </CustomAction>
    </CustomActions>
    <Templates>
      <RibbonTemplates Id="Mscrm.Templates"></RibbonTemplates>
    </Templates>
    <CommandDefinitions>
        <CommandDefinition Id="javascript.Command">
            <EnableRules>
                <EnableRule Id="Mscrm.Enabled"/>
            </EnableRules>
            <DisplayRules />
            <Actions>
                <JavaScriptFunction Library="$webresource:ave_eidlauncher"  FunctionName="launcheid">
                </JavaScriptFunction>
            </Actions>
        </CommandDefinition>    
    </CommandDefinitions>
    <RuleDefinitions>
      <TabDisplayRules />
      <DisplayRules />
      <EnableRules />
    </RuleDefinitions>
    <LocLabels />
  </RibbonDiffXml>
  <EntityMaps />
  <EntityRelationships />
  <OrganizationSettings />
  <optionsets />
  <Languages>
    <Language>1033</Language>
    <Language>1036</Language>
  </Languages>
</ImportExportXml>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Kind Regards,
Frederic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Application ribbon is being edited in the example.  The Application Ribbon XML will apply the customizations to all entities.  That is why the author used `{!EntityLogicalName}` instead on explictly naming the entity.  If you only want to add the button to a single entity you need to add the entity instead of the Application Ribbon to the solution before you export.

This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334341.aspx) should help.